# Convert VB.NET to C# interface

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need help in converting a VB.NET interface to one in C#. The code below defines an Event and raises it in a method.

```
Public Event CampaignDetailSelected(ByVal listItem As ListItem) _
Implements ICampaignMaintenanceView.CampaignDetailSelected

...

RaiseEvent CampaignDetailSelected(DirectCast(lsbCampaignDetail.SelectedItem, ListItem))
```

The interface for it is:

```
Public Interface ICampaignMaintenanceView
    Event CampaignDetailSelected(listItem As ListItem)
    ...
End Interface
```

When I push the interface above through a converter, it converts the Event but also includes a delegate, which is not allowed in C#.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: delegate not allowed in C#? Are you sure? Or what do you mean?!

Comment: Seems to me that would be an Action<ListItem>

Comment: looks like the `Event` declaration in `VB.NET` hides the `underlying delegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the many issues I've had with C# versus VB.NET, as much as I love C#, VB.NET makes events simpler.

```
// Placed outside of the class
public delegate void CampaignDetailSelectedEventHandler(ListItem listItem);

// Test class to show to convert from vb.net to C# 
public class Test : ICampaignMaintenanceView
{
    public event CampaignDetailSelectedEventHandler CampaignDetailSelected; 


    protected virtual void OnCampaignDetailSelected(ListItem listItem)
    {
        if (CampaignDetailSelected != null)
        {
            CampaignDetailSelected(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C# delegate and interface should look like:

```
public delegate void CampaignDetailSelectedEventHandler(ListItem listItem);

public interface ICampaignMaintenanceView
{
    event CampaignDetailSelectedEventHandler CampaignDetailSelected;
}
```